# swfobject flashes white before swf has loaded

Tags: swfobject

I have the following code, I have set the bgcolor and still my page flashes white prior to swf loading. Basically i want the background to always be black, my page body tag has a black background.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var path = "/media/19519/la_03.swf";
var videowidth = "955";
var videoid = "swf1454";
var videoheight = "540";
var flashvars = {};
var attributes = {};
var params = {
wmode: "opaque",
bgcolor: "#000000",  
  allowfullscreen: "true",
  allscriptaccess: "always"
};

swfobject.embedSWF(path, videoid, videowidth, videoheight, "9.0.0", flashvars, params, attributes);

        </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's probably from your swf loading. I had a similar problem with a large swf and the way I got it to stop was to pause the swf in the first frame until it was done loading. Then just put an empty frame at 1 and make it the bg color. Once the swf is ready to go the animation starts

Comment: thanks, yeah i guess the swf need to be pre-loaded. I'm not the author of the swfs. Do you know of any feature of swfobject or jquery that could maybe make this a little smoother.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the html element containing the swf is black too.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but for people who stumble upon this post via search engines:

A flash of white is sometimes a byproduct of SWFObject's 'autohide' feature (CSS is used to hide the fallback content before the SWF loads). If you don't want to see the flash of white, try disabling SWFObject's autohide feature:

SWFObject documentation:

- What's new in 2.2: [The option to switch off SWFObject's default show/hide behavior](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/wiki/whats_new#10._The_option_to_switch_off_SWFObject%27s_default_show/hide)
- SWFObject 2.2 API docs: [swfobject.switchOffAutoHideShow()](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/wiki/api#swfobject.switchOffAutoHideShow%28%29)

Of course, how you build your SWF will also impact whether you see a flash of white.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the issue was in background color of the swf file.
When not explicitly set, it defaults to white until loaded. So just set it explicitly and you won't have a white flash.

```
var params = {bgcolor:"#000000"};
swfobject.embedSWF("my.swf", "flash", "100%", "100%", "10.0.0", false, {}, params);
```